# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27.lib'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycrypto

I was trying to compile pycrypto-2.6.1 from source for Python 2.7.10 64-Bit Windows Version and facing the following error.

```
Processing pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\sivasuba\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ecznz_\pycrypto-2.6.1\setup.cfg
Running pycrypto-2.6.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\sivasuba\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ecznz_\pycrypto-2.6.1\egg-dist-tmp-us3gka
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
winrand.c
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27.lib'
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Users\\sivasuba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104
```

Googling didn't help much. Any help on this would be appreciated.

P.S. I am not looking for pre-complied binaries. The requirement is to build it from source.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like your linker doesn't find python27.lib library.

LIB and LIBPATH are windows environment variables which are being used by the linker and compiler.

In which folder do you have python27.lib on your computer?

please confirm that LIB environment variable include the path for the python27.lib

If it didn't solve your problem - try adding python27.lib path also to LIBPATH

Answer (score 13):

Doing the following worked for me:

1. python27.lib is located in 'libs' folder under Python27 (folder where python is installed on windows)
   [image]
2. Add 'LIB' environment variable to the that points to the directory/folder containing python27.lib library:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This worked here:

On CMakeLists.txt add this line:

```
link_directories(C:\\python\\libs)
```

Note that my Python installation is at C:\python

Comment: Very obnoxious that CMake, pybind, etc. doesn't pick this up and do it for you.

Comment: That may work but it's non-portable. Ideally *FIND_PACKAGE(Python3 ....)* should be used, along with a call like *TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mytarget ${Python3_LIBRARIES})* (that's assuming Python3 of course).

Answer (score 0):

if its giving,
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python26.lib'

Do as following :

1.Right click your project -> go to properties -> Linker -> Input -> Ignore 
  specific Default Libraries -> type 'python26.lib'

Hope this will help !
Thanks.
Best regards,
Janath Francisco.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is to add the directory to the linker's include directories:

In VS 2015 it is Project settings - Linker - General - Additional Library Directories

You can either edit the line directly, or click the small button on the end of the line and edit via GUI